# Replacing string in a file using PHP and HTML

Tags: php, html, string, filesystems

I want to replace a String in a file, the problem here is that there are Strings in it which are quite simmilar.
There is a String "[100]" , then one with "[101]" etc. 
I want to replace just the inside of the brackets and then give it back to the file.

Problem is that the Variables keep beeing empty and my Str_replace doesnt do anything.
Anyone knows where I went off in this?

These are my variables and strings to replace, which i got from another .html file. It reads the file and gives me all entries for the strings in brackets. Now I want to change them on klicking them

```
<table style="padding-top:10px" align=center>
<tr>
    <td rowspan = "6">
        <table>
        <?php include("./sip_table.php"); foreach($dw as $row):?>
        <tr>
        <?php foreach($row as $k=>$cell):?>
        <td><?php include("./fill.php"); echo "<button id=\"{$cell}\" onclick=\"ausfüllen('{$cell}','{$name}','{$nummer}','{$pw}')\">{$cell}</button>"; ?></td>
        <?php endforeach ?>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach ?>
        </table></td> </tr>
<tr>
    <td> 
        <table> 
            <tr> <td> Durchwahl </td> <td> <input type="text" id="nv_durchwahl" name="nv_dw" value=""></td> </tr>
            <tr> <td> Anzeigename </td> <td> <input type="text" id="nv_anzeigename" name="nv_ane" value=""></td> </tr>
            <tr> <td> Angezeigte Durchwahl </td> <td> <input type="text" id="nv_anzeigenummer" name="nv_anm" value=""> </td> </tr>
            <tr> <td> Passwort </td> <td> <input type="text" id="nv_passwort" name="nv_pw" value=""> </td> </tr>
            <tr><td><br/></td><td><br/></td></tr>
            <tr> 
                <td><input type="submit" id="nv_speichern" name="nv_speichern" value="Speichern"></td> 
                <td><input type="submit" id="nv_delete" name="nv_delete" value="L&ouml;schen"> </td> 
                <td> <input type="submit" id="nv_add" name="nv_add" value="Hinzuf&uuml;gen"> </td></tr>
        </table> 
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

This is my replace .php script:

```
<?php
    $file = '/etc/asterisk/sip_dev.conf';
    $content = file_get_contents($file);
    //Replace Durchwahl
    $content = str_replace('[{$_SESSION["dw"]}]', '[{$_GET["nv_durchwahl"]}]', $content);
    //Replace Name & Anzeigenummer
    $content = str_replace('callerid={$_SESSION["name"]} <{$_SESSION["nummer"]}>', 'callerid={$_GET["nv_anzeigename"]} <{$_GET["nv_anzeigenummer"]}>', $content);
    //Replace Passwd
    $content = str_replace('secret={$_SESSION["pw"]}', 'secret={$_GET["nv_passwort"]}', $content);
    file_put_contents($file, $content);
?>
```

The script to fill the editform is that:

```
<script>
function ausfüllen(dw, name, nummer, pw) {
document.getElementById("nv_durchwahl").value = dw;
document.getElementById("nv_anzeigename").value = name;
document.getElementById("nv_anzeigenummer").value = nummer;
document.getElementById("nv_passwort").value = pw;
}
</script>
```

Comment: What is the problem exactly? And you should post the javascript as well.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I edited it and posted my Editform and the Script aswell.
It doesnt do anything and my Variables keep beeing empty (if i access them in the other .php file)